# How to abbreviate windows path for use in batch files

Tags: cmd, path

I want to abbreviate paths, ie.

`C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.9.1`

I have seen it abbreviated as:

`C:\Analog~1\CrossC~1.0`

However, that abbreviation opens:

`C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.6.0`

How does that abreviation work I dont get it, I want it to diferentiate from

`C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.9.0`

Comment: `C:\Analog~1\CrossC~1.0` is not an abbreviated path. Windows still stores long file/folder names also with short 8.3 file/folder names if this feature is not explicitly disabled in Windows registry. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. Next run `dir /?` and read again the output help. You can run for example `dir C:\Ana* /AD /X` to see the short 8.3 name of `C:\Analog Devices`. Run also `for /?` and read output help. Run `for %I in ("C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.9.1") do @echo %~sI` to get displayed the short path.

Comment: The order the 8.3 filenames are created in will be the order they are numbered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shorter name to type, use an environment variable.

```
SET "ADCES_HOME=C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.9.1"
```

Then, use it in other code.

```
DIR "%ADCES_HOME%"
DIR "%ADCES_HOME%\lib"
```

You may be able to convert a long name to its 8.3 equivalent using a FOR loop. Double the % character if this is used in a .bat file script.

```
FOR %D IN ("C:\Analog Devices\CrossCore Embedded Studio 2.9.1") DO (SET "ADCES_HOME=%~sD")
```